# How to pass command with quotes to system()?

Tags: c

I have no idea how to pass command like:

```
echo -e \"\E[1;3mHello!"
```

to `system()`, since I have to put it in quotation marks cause it's `const char`, any help?

Comment: Just escape them with backslashes.

Comment: Why would you use `system()` to call `echo`? Just use C's built-in output functions.

Comment: That command won't work, it has mismatched quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes need to be escaped in strings, as do backslashes:

```
system("bash -c 'echo -e \"\\E[1;3mHello!\"'");
```

Comment: Well, acording to your solution it prints "-e \E[1;3mHello!" instead of "Hello!" with specific graphic functions called.

Comment: @MateuszTrzeciak It looks like it was calling the internal "echo" command for /bin/sh, while it's the internal "echo" for /bin/bash that supports this.  Updated to specifically call out `bash`.

Comment: Thanks, now it works perfectly. Woudn't have guessed it without you.

Comment: @MateuszTrzeciak Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.